# Limit file size for "image url" field

Tags: images, contact-image

We use the "image URL" field via profile to allow members to upload their organization logo. We would like to limit the file size a user can upload. Are there any options for us?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Drupal, Joomla or WP?

Comment: We are using WP and CiviCRM 4.7.14.

Comment: Are you uploading other files that will be larger than the image file size?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement a hook via PHP to validate the profile when it is submitted: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_processProfile/.

Someone else may want to chime in. I'm not sure if you can use form hooks with profiles. Otherwise you may check this: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/

You can then use PHP to validate the file size:
Check this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153224/how-to-limit-file-upload-type-file-size-in-php).